# Cannot catch click event on FeatureLayer in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, event-listener

I've got a `SceneView` with a `FeatureLayer`, and I'm trying to catch every click on a `PictureMarkerSymbol` to display additional data under the map.

The map works well, so do symbols and popups, but I never catch any event, am I missing something?

```
require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/SceneView",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer",
    "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
    "dojo/on"
], function(
    Map, SceneView, FeatureLayer, UniqueValueRenderer, PictureMarkerSymbol, on
) {

    var map = new Map({ ... });   
    var view = new SceneView({ ... });

    view.then(function() {

        var renderer = new UniqueValueRenderer({ ... });
        var pins = [...];
        pins.forEach(function (element) {
          renderer.addUniqueValueInfo(element,
            new PictureMarkerSymbol({ ... })
          );
        });

        layerMarkers = new FeatureLayer({
            title: "Labels Layer",
            url: "...",
            definitionExpression: "...",
            renderer: renderer,
            outFields: ["*"],
            popupTemplate: { ... }
        });

        layerMarkers.on("click", function (evt) {  
            console.log(evt.graphic.attributes);  // No output??
        }); 

        map.add(layerMarkers);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out how to catch these events.
I'm not allowed to listen for `click` events on a `FeatureLayer`, nor on a `Map`, but I still can listen it on my `SceneView`, and use the `hitTest()` function to get the related symbol:

```
// Listen for SceneView click events
view.on("click", function (evt) {  
  // Search for symbols on click's position
  view.hitTest(evt.screenPoint)
    .then(function(response){
      // Retrieve the first symbol
      var graphic = response.results[0].graphic;
      if (graphic) {
        // We now have access to its attributes
        console.log(graphic.attributes);
      }
    });
});
```